# How to preload a MKMapView before the UIViewController will be presented?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I modally present a `UIViewController` with a `MKMapView` in it. But the `UIViewController` should only be presented, after the `MKMapView` finished loading/render a specific region. So if the `UIViewController` is presented, the map should be already there. I need it to be loaded for a smooth transition between those `UIViewController`. Of course I show a `UIActivityIndicatorView` to the user.

What I have done yet:

```
let mapViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mapView") as! MapViewViewController
let _ = mapViewController.view //viewDidLoad gets called and views are loaded

mapViewController.set(region: Region)
self.mapInfoCard.loadingIndicator.startAnimating()

//called on MKMapView´s mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView) delegate function
mapViewController.finishedHandler = {
   self.mapInfoCard.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
   self.present(mapViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView)` was never called. The `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool)` delegate function gets called after I set the region, but `mapViewWillStartLoadingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView)` or `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView)` never. Only if I present the `UIViewController` without waiting for die `finishedHandler`.

Comment: why don't you add the delegate of the map to your parent view controller, and mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(:_) will be called in your parent and then present your mapViewController

Comment: @HadyNourallah yeah could do that, but that doesn´t change the fact the map is not loading (look at the edit, just edited the question)